# Determine whether a set is dense in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: irrational-numbers, rational-numbers

we just learned in class about dense sets in $\Bbb R$ .
We learned how to prove that a set is dense in $\Bbb R$ but not how to disprove.
I got the following question: Determine whether the set is dense in $\Bbb R$ .
$ A =\lbrace a \in \Bbb {R \setminus Q} : a^2 \in \Bbb Q \rbrace$
. I tried proving it but without any success. I also tried disproving it but I think I lack the proper tools. I tried to find two real numbers that don't have any element of A between them.

Any help will be welcomed.

Comment: It is dense, so look for a proof.

Comment: You just have to prove that for any interval $(x,y)$ you can find $a\in A\cap (x,y)$. This is not so hard using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ contains all real numbers of the form $\alpha\sqrt{2}$ where $\alpha\ne 0$ is rational. Take any real number $\beta\ne 0$ and $\gamma=\beta/\sqrt{2}$. The number $\gamma$ can be approximated arbitrarily close by rational numbers $\alpha$. Hence $\beta$ can be approximated arbitrarily close by numbers from $A$. Hence $A$ is dense.